# Print asterisk after some integer

Tags: java

So i have homework question about java code. the question is how to print integer from 1 to 100 with a pattern below

12345*678*910111213*141516*1718192021*...

so here it is my code so far, but the output is not the same as the pattern.

```
public class PlayPattern1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=100;i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            if (i%5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
                for (int j = i+1;j<=100;j++) {
                    System.out.print(j);
                    if (j%3 == 0) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

can any one help me?

Comment: One line answer. `System.out.println("12345*678*910111213*141516*1718192021*");` - If you want more help, I suggest you explain what the pattern is...

Comment: Is the pattern to print an asterisk after 5 numbers, then 3, then 5, then 3, and so on?

Comment: ^ Also you should read up on how to post a question, it would be nice to know the pattern and know what output you are currently receiving.

Comment: @SinanÜnür 13? So, % 5, % 3, and fibonacci?

Comment: I addition to what is the pattern, what is your actual problem? We can't fix something if we don't know what is broken.

Comment: @AntonH yeah it is, i believe so. so i choose devide it with 5 and 3

Comment: @Tezra the pattern is after increment 5 number you have to add an asterisk and after increment 3 number after the last asterik you have to add another an asterik and so on like that

Comment: @dedypuji So alternating every 5'th and 3'rd item? You can use a countdown int and print an * when it hits zero, and use a Boolean to remember if you should reset it to 5 or 3 this time.

Comment: @dedypuji Increment by 5 then 3 is not at all the same as divide by 3 and 5. 13, for example, fits the first, not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with a `count` variable, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int i;
    int count = 1;
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        if(count % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
        }else if(count % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
                count = 0;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 13 and 21 do not match your criteria.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated the answer and executed the code locally. It matches now..

Comment: thanks dude, i understand now